# Error:Can't resolve 'demorouting/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' in 'C:\Users\

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, node-modules

I'm a newbie to angular, I created "demorouting" folder in VS code then I install (npm install bootstrap) to the directory. After that I copy the relative path of bootstrap.min.js file to angular.jason file 'script' section. Then I created a component called navbar and add some html elements. Finally I typed np serve on terminal and this error came:
Error: Can't resolve 'demorouting/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' in 'C:\Users...

I tried to delete node_modules folder and then reinstalled again but nothing changed. [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aHti.jpg)